# Using JQuery Validation with JQuery Notification plugin

Tags: jquery, validation, notifications

I am using JQuery validation plugin to validate one of my forms, however now I have come across another very cool JQuery plugin, called "Noty", its for Notifications.

Now I want the Noty plugin to notify for errors on form. Can I call custom methods from JQuery validator for success or failure of each field ?

Comment: take a look to `errorPlacement` to see if that fits for the part of custom function on failure.

Answer (score 1):

The `showErrors` property of the options you pass accepts a callback to run when messages are displayed. You should put your code that runs Noty in here.